How to create a "shared library" intended to be statically resident at a fixed memory location
I am looking for a proper way to create firmware components for a following architecture without inventing the wheel.
Consider that the system has multiple firmware executables that can be either loaded dynamically, or execute in order by passing the control to each other. And there is a common functionality that is statically loaded into a known memory address and is callable by each of the executable firmware components:
|-------------------|
|      Executable 1 |
|-------------------|
|        ...        |
|-------------------|
|      Executable 2 |
|-------------------|
|        ...        |
|-------------------| <--- fixed address
|  Shared "library" |
|-------------------|

I'd like to be able to create the executables by linking their code with some artifact produced by the build process of the "library",  that is something like:
ld <some options and input objects> --just-symbols=library.syms  executable.elf

(both the library artifact and the executable will be flattened into a raw binary later, but this step is implied and isn't important for the question sake).
Now, the question is how to actually build this library knowing the final location it would be stored at? Traditional static libraries are usually linked with the executable and are placed according to it's linker script. One way I saw, is to actually produce another (elf) executable with a dummy main function and a specific linker script and use it as the "library" in the question, but it looks somewhat hack-ish way to me. In addition I am not sure it is safe and no functions that are expected to be exported are optimized out.
** Assuming GNU cross toolchain and whatever binutils in the disposal

Is Is there anyway to force loader to load shared library at a fixed address? what you are looking for?

@TedLyngmo TBH I am not much familiar with shared libraries as I considered these to be exclusively OS-specific.. looks like these are being linked standalone and have a defined memory map? If that's the case, it might be exactly what I am looking for.

Yeah, it looks like it could work. I just went through the steps in the answer there and got a .so with addresses that looks ok, but if it's usable, I don't know.

I think you're "shared library" should be built as a freestanding executable at a fixed address. That way, it has no relocated symbols. Then, --just-symbols should work against it. Also, I might make it use the lowest address (e.g. 0, 0x1000, etc.)

@CraigEstey So yeah, building as executable is the option I am aware of, I am just not sure it is the clean way to do so and also not clear on what will happen to the exported functions if they aren't being used by the executable itself.

You can tell the linker to not elide exported but unused symbols [I think]. If not, you can write a build script that scans (via readelf -s (e.g.)) all the .o files that make it up, and build a table of all the symbols. (e.g.) `void *all_symbols[] = { func1, func2, &sym1, &sym2, ... }; Compile this and link it in. This should force all symbols to be included. As a byproduct, it also forms a bit of an indirect jump table and you could use that as well.

@CraigEstey Thanks, will look into this. Do you have some specific objection to the *.so approach as Ted suggested?

If the lib has no external references and no relocation of its symbols, they're largely the same. The basic approach is nearly identical (with/without -shared).But, with executables it leaves off the relocation sections of the ELF.  But, since you're flattening to a binary anyway, it may be a moot point.

@CraigEstey Just FYI here is a question about the as-executable approach, looks like the OP encountered the issue I was afraid of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207402/how-to-link-against-just-symbols-correctly

@CraigEstey Bad luck with -shared on a bare-metal toolchain (riscv). They do not support it :(

Not totally surprised ;-) For binary images, I think you need a flat file that is a byte-for-byte image of the target boot rom/disk (e.g. The first executable inst is at offset 0). So, you have to roll your own format, similar to a .wav, .mp4, ELF that have headers for each section (e.g.) magic,length,type. You'd transfer control to section 0 (e.g. shared) and it will probe for the other ones. Probably need more info on the final format for the platform as well as what "dynamic" loading means in this context and how you want to chain them. Using qemu-system-riscv* for test?

@CraigEstey I think as a workaround I can just compile it as "executable". Looks like it does not require main or entry point to be defined, but I need to mark all of the exported functions with __attribute__((used)) and link with --gc-keep-exported. I also wanted to take advantage of -fvisibility, but looks like it has no effect on statically linked binaries for some reason.

Although an extra step (objcopy --localize-hidden) can work around this

Visibility is purely an ELF thing, but I don't think I'd worry about it. With embedded, we must trust one another :-) As to used, it may not be necessary. I just build a program with int foo(void) { return 37; } int main(void) { return 0; } and it included foo in the output executable (even with -O2)

This is done by "linker script". https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html
As a very primitive example, you can do something like this:
SECTIONS {
  SecA 0x10000 : {
    foo.o (.text)
    bar.o (.text)
  }
  SecB : { * (.text) }
  .data : { *(.data) }
}

This would put all functions from object file foo.o at the specified absolute address. Once object foo.o is done, functions from the bar.o will be the second one.
Functions, from all other objects, with no regard to sorting object files would be after.
Finally you would have a separate section for global variables.
Please note, you cannot specify locations of functions. If you have two or more functions in an object - they would be put into final output as one batch. But you can go with a one file = one function approach. At least for functions which would require absolute placement.

Thanks, I am aware of linker scripts. My problem is what the actual artifact type should it be built into, as a regular .a library isn't being linked standalone and therefore can't use a linker script. Looks like shared library .so could work. BTW, you can place functions at specific addresses by asking the compiler to create a section per function, and then in the linker script you can control the placement of these sections.

A shared library cannot be in a fixed absolute position, as you cannot control where in your application map it is going to be possible to load.
The problem is that a program can have a free segment in which to load and run the library, but another program can have that same virtual memory segment filled with a different thing.
In this scenario you don't know where in your virtual address space will be possible to put the shared library, ensuring that all potential programs that use it will have that same segment available.
This is why a shared library must be compiled using -fpic to allow the code to be position independent code.
